# Is there a way to replay bosses?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Excluding New Game+ modes, is there a way to fight a boss a second time? The boss indicator is still lit on the map, and I now have the abilities required to defeat the boss, so I'd like to fight them again. However, the door is closed and won't let me in.

[image: Boss door]

Comment: Are you using the Architect to lock the castle down?

Comment: @UnderscoreZero : No. Does that matter?

Comment: I guess I was mistaken but I thought you could re-fight bosses if the castle had changed, but according to the wiki, it's not. http://rogue-legacy.wikia.com/wiki/Bosses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot fight bosses multiple times in a single playthrough. I like to think it's because the rewards of the bosses are huge, and being able to simply farm them over and over would be too easy to rack up tons of quick cash.

Though this isn't the same as the actual boss fight you're referring to, you can sort of fight them repeated if you find their respective Obols, when you pray for a blessing at the shrine. You can do this:

> once you've beaten the boss and given it's respective Obol to Charron, you are allowed to fight the boss again but with a fixed class per boss, and the boss itself has special powers making it a completely different and much more challenging fight. If you die during this fight you lose nothing and are placed in the same boss room. From here you can try again as much as you like or continue through the castle as usual. I myself haven't completed any of these, so I'm not sure what happens if you win this fight.

Comment: You need to beat all of those special bosses, including one for The Fountain, to completely beat the game.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. Strangely enough I had one of the Obols on the playthrough where I took the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've finished the game, you can play again, but the game will be harder. You can kill all the bosses again, and get to the final boss again as well, just by playing like you did first time. But you can't fight them twice on the same playthrough without finishing the game.

Comment: "Excluding New Game+ modes"